# Zuul routing doesn't work, gives 404 : Spring Boot+ Cloud+ Zuul

Tags: rest, spring-boot, servlet-filters, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am working on a flow where I have ng4+boot app running on https://host_a:8080 and a backend service at https://host_b:8080 with some APIs.

I have `RestController`/`Path` at both the hosts, i.e. I need some urls to hit `localhost` (`host_a`) and others to `host_b`.

In `application.yml`, I have tried almost all possible combinations of Zuul routes but still getting 404 for all host_b rest APIs. `host_a` APIs work well.

Note: We have this working when there is no rest API on host_a and no custom filter on `host_a`.

1. Is there something wrong working with filter? I don't see any log from zuul filter now after I added this controller to `host_a`

I am aware that I can use forward property to route to `localhost` which works well. But somehow `host_b` rest all gives 404 error.

My implementation requirements-

1. http://host_a:8080/api/abc/user to hit at `localhost` i.e. `host_a`
2. http://host_a:8080/api/xyz/getall to hit at `host_b`
3. Important- Need a custom zuul filter which adds certain headers to request before it's routed to host_b as explained in point 2. - Already at place, but cannot see logs inside it now.

What I tried already-

```
zuul: 
  routes:
      xyz:
        path: /api/xyz/**
        url: http://host_b:8080/api/xyz
```

I tried almost everything, using prefix, strip-prefix,  only host in url, using forward for local routing, etc. Nothing works.

Kindly help me with the possible causes I may be ignoring or if missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Zuul, have you tried going to the /trace and /routes pages to help you troubleshoot?

Comment: Yes, route mapping seems to be fine. It displays routes. But is there anyway to check whether the request has been routed? Which host_b url it points to upon request from host_a?

Comment: >  But is there anyway to check whether the request has been routed?

Yes.  /trace.

Comment: Let me check that today and update

Comment: Cannot GET /trace. 404 for this from host_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve issues.
1. I had to change jersey @Path to spring @RestController

2. Changed Zuul Filter order from 1 to 999.

Works well now.